# Compartilhando modulo globalmente no Angular

Tags: angular

Criei um projeto utilizado a ferramenta Angular-Cli e juntamente instalei

> npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
>
> npm install --save @angular/animations

E como na própria documentação explica eu importei os módulos do angular material em um arquivo separado: (angular-material-module.ts):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
browser/animations';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatCardModule, MatIconModule, MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, 
MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
       CommonModule,

       BrowserAnimationsModule,
       FlexLayoutModule,
       MatCardModule,
       MatIconModule,
       MatToolbarModule,
       MatButtonModule,
       MatFormFieldModule,
       MatInputModule
   ],    
   exports: [
       BrowserAnimationsModule,
       FlexLayoutModule,
       MatCardModule,
       MatIconModule,
       MatToolbarModule,
       MatButtonModule,
       MatFormFieldModule,
       MatInputModule
   ]
})
export class AngularMaterialModule { }
```

Em seguida importei o modulo em meu modulo principal (app.module.ts):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularMaterialModule } from './compartilhado/angular- 
   material/angular-material.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { MainModule } from './main/main.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,

        AppRoutingModule,
        AngularMaterialModule,


        MainModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Para testar se estava tudo funcionando corretamente, eu inseri alguns componentes na tela inicial app.component.html, sendo assim funcionou corretamente.

Porém criei alguns sub módulos do módulo principal, conforme exemplificado na imagem abaixo:
[image: Imagem demonstrativa]

Sendo assim dentro do component cadastro-curriculo.component.html, fui utilizar os components do angular-material, porém apresentou um erro, informando que os elementos do angular-material não foram encontrado:
[image: erros-angular-material]

Para fins de teste, importei o modulo que tinha criado com os components do angular-material (AngularMaterialModule), diretamente no modulo do componente (CadastroCurriculoModule), aí funcionou ...

Gostaria de saber se tem é possível que eu importe o modulo (AngularMaterialModule) que criei com os componentes do angular-material, de uma forma global e fique disponível para todos os módulos e components do projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, não tem.
Esta é a forma correta mesmo do angular trabalhar a modularização.
Se você precisar dos components globais, tem sempre que importar o módulo.

O que nós fazemos com frequência em projetos Angular é criar um módulo **SharedModule** e nele concentrar e exportar tudo que for global ao aplicativo, colocar lá todas as libs e módulos que serão usados globalmente. E a cada novo módulo que você criar, basta importar o SharedModule.

Assim fica mais fácil importar só um módulo ( o shared) em cada novo que você criar, do que importar vários. um exemplo de SharedModule seria:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        LayoutComponent,
        LayoutHeaderComponent,
        LayoutSideMenuComponent,
        LayoutFooterComponent,
        LayoutControlSidebarComponent,
        NoLinkDirective,
        CheckRoleDirective,
        CheckAccessDirective,
        LimpaDirective,
        LoadingComponent,
        ModalCallComponent,
        ModalConfirmComponent,
        ModalAlertComponent,
        PainelComponent,
        PrimaryButtonComponent,
        DangerButtonComponent,
        ModalSenhaComponent,
        PaginacaoComponent,
        MenuCom0Component,
        MenuRootComponent,
        MenuCom1Component,
        MenuCom2Component,
        MenuEnf1Component,
        MenuPsi1Component,
        MenuMed1Component,
        MenuAdm1Component,
        MenuMkt1Component,
        ClienteResponsivoComponent,
        MenuAdm2Component,
        BuscaTopoComponent,
        SnackbarUpdateComponent,
        ModalLogComponent,
        LogItemComponent,
        MenuCos0Component,
        CartaoComponent,
        MortosStatsComponent,
        ClienteLogComponent,
        DocumentosListComponent,
        DashboardAlertComponent,
        LembreteLigacaoComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        FormsModule,
        NoLinkDirective,
        CheckRoleDirective,
        CheckAccessDirective,
        LimpaDirective,
        LayoutComponent,
        LoadingComponent,
        ModalCallComponent,
        ModalConfirmComponent,
        ModalAlertComponent,
        PainelComponent,
        PrimaryButtonComponent,
        DangerButtonComponent,
        ModalSenhaComponent,
        PaginacaoComponent,
        ClienteResponsivoComponent,
        ModalLogComponent,
        CartaoComponent,
        MortosStatsComponent,
        ClienteLogComponent,
        DocumentosListComponent,
        LembreteLigacaoComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        MessageService,
        NotificationService,
        EventEmitterService,
        GenericService,
        HttpStatusService,
        NoLinkDirective,
        CheckRoleDirective,

        // services
        UsersService,
        UtilService,
        ClienteService,
        EmailService
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Repare que ele é extenso, mas contempla tudo que é global à aplicação. De outros módulos à components e directives.

Comment: Muito bacana, no meu projeto aqui acabei realizando exatamente está abordagem mesmo ... Não sabia se era a melhor abordagem mas aqui no projeto funcionou bem